# MATLAB trained neural network weight has less values than input

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am having a problem with matlab. I have trained a neural network using neural network toolbox with 5 input parameters and 1 hidden layer. When I have extracted weights using `net.iw{1}` i got 5 weights. But when i extended my data set by adding 2 additional parameters I am getting 6 weights instead of 7. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: How many neurons does your hidden layer have? Usually, a fully connected network has amount of input neurons times amount of hidden neurons weights for the first layer, and amount of hidden neurons times amount of output neurons weights for the second layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my data set was bad. One of the features was always 0 so MATLAB didn't used it.